# ESMTP error malformed address: ORCPT=rfc822

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

when trying to send a mail out I am seeing the folowing error in the maillog

client address has been obfuscated

`Apr  5 18:15:18 my.mailserver.co.uk postfix-01/smtp[10626]: 1234567: to=<client@client.address.com>, relay=mail3.gridhost.co.uk[95.142.156.18]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.15/0/1/0.24, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail3.gridhost.co.uk[95.142.156.18] said: 501 <client@client.address.com> ORCPT=rfc822;client@client.address.com: malformed address: ORCPT=rfc822;client@clie may not follow <client@client.address.com>  (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

I performed the following manunal test and was able to reproduce the error

```
$ telnet mail3.gridhost.co.uk 25
Trying 95.142.156.28...
Connected to mail3.gridhost.co.uk.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail-lb-002.london.gridhost.co.uk ESMTP ready
EHLO mydomain.co.uk
250-mail-lb-002.london.gridhost.co.uk
250-SIZE 50485760
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 STARTTLS
MAIL FROM: test@domain.co.uk
250 2.0.0 OK

RCPT TO: <client@client.address.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE,DELAY ORCPT=rfc822;client@client.address.com
501 <client@client.address.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE,DELAY ORCPT=rfc822;client@client.address.com: malformed address: NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE,DELAY ORC may not follow <client@client.address.com>
```

Without the DSN response request it works ok

```
RCPT TO: client@client.address.com
250 Accepted
^]
```

if I try without the 
using postfix-2.6.6-2.el6.x86_64 on centos 6.8
any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: My first thought is that the remote mail server is broken. It advertises support for DSN but doesn't actually accept the parameter.

Comment: That was my thought, I tried to contact the ISP but they wouldn't talk to me as I'm not a customer.